# Makefile target name compared to string

Tags: makefile

In a makefile I'm trying to compare the target name with a string, and depending on this set a variable with a string or another.
This example illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
ifeq ($@,"Target_A")
 THE_PATH="Path_a"
 THE_TARGET=$@
else
 THE_PATH="Path_b"
 THE_TARGET=$@
endif

Target_A:
    @echo $(THE_PATH)
    @echo $(THE_TARGET)

Target_B:
    @echo $(THE_PATH)
    @echo $(THE_TARGET)
```

This is the output when I call make passing Target_A and when I call it passing Target_B:

```
$ make Target_A
Path_b
Target_A

$ make Target_B
Path_b
Target_B
```

The fact that I always get "Path_b" indicates the ifeq always evaluates to false, but you can see that $@ contained the right string.

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: What do you want with `make Target_A Target_B` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want target-specific variables:

```
Target_A: THE_PATH="Path_a"
Target_A:
    @echo $(THE_PATH)
```

Since contents of a (regular) variable are expanded each time it's used, `THE_TARGET=$@` can be made global.

---

Target-specific variables are only accesible in a target they belong to, and its dependencies.

Normally this is enough, but if you need to have *global* variables, you can use the same code you have in the question, with the condition changed to this:

```
ifneq ($(filter Target_A,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),)
```

`$@` (which you tried to use) only works inside of a recipe, and expands to a target name that the recipe builds.

`$(MAKECMDGOALS)` is a global variable that contains all targets specified (as command-line parameters) when invoking `make`.

This option will only work if the target you're looking for was specified as a command-line parameter.

Comment: Thanks, $(MAKECMDGOALS) is what I needed. I'm still curious as to why THE_TARGET contains the right string if $@ is not set outside the recipes...

Comment: @Dan The contents of a variable are normally expanded when the variable is used, not when you assign a value to it. See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors